# Is rearanging allowed when we talk about asymptotic equivalence?

Tags: asymptotics

I am examining a certain set of integers,  $M$.
Let's say, the amount of integers less or equal than $x$ is $S(x)$.
Now my studies show that the density of primes in this set $M$ is the double density of primes in the naturals.
In formula
$$
\operatorname{d}_M(x) \sim 2\operatorname{d}(x) \text{ for } x\to\infty.
$$
Let's say $\pi(x)$ is the prime counting function and $\pi_M(x)$ is the amount of primes in $M$ which are $\leq x$.
Then we have
$$
\operatorname{d}_M(x) = \frac{\pi_M(x)}
{\operatorname{S}(x)}  \;\;
\text{ and } 
 \;\;
\operatorname{d}(x) = \frac{\pi(x)}{x}.
$$
Now I wonder whether I may do the following:
$$
\operatorname{d}_M(x) \sim 2\operatorname{d}(x) 
\Longleftrightarrow
\frac{\pi_M(x)}
{\operatorname{S}(x)}
\sim
2\frac{\pi(x)}{x}
\Longleftrightarrow 
|\pi_M(x)| 
\stackrel{?}{\sim}
2\cdot\frac{\pi(x)}{x} \cdot \operatorname{S}(x).
$$

Because if I use the definition of $\sim$ I get
$$
\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \frac{\frac{\pi_M(x)}
{\operatorname{S}(x)}}{2\cdot\frac{\pi(x)}{x}} = 1,
$$
but the term in question would be
$$
\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \pi_M(x)
 = 
\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}2\cdot\frac{\pi(x)}{x}\cdot \operatorname{S}(x).
$$

I don't know whether this is allowed.
Nevertheless I know from the prime theorem that we can estimate $\pi(x)$ by calculating $\frac{\pi(x)}{x}$ which is actually what I want to do here for $\pi_M(x)$